# Css class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, telerik

I apply my css class:

```
.InvalidControl
{
      background-color:lightcoral;
}
```

to DOM element of Telerik's control (it is input type = "text" actually) with jQuery

```
$(inputObjectDOM).addClass(this.InvalidControlCssClassName);
```

This does not change background. When I open DOM explorer in IE I see my background-color styled crossed out. If I apply this css background-color
property directly it is showing. DOM explorer shows various (Telerik's own) classes applied on this element. How can I make my class to work first ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this:

```
.InvalidControl
{
      background-color:lightcoral !important;
}
```

Comment: I just tried to, but it says my reputation is too low here.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please select it as the answer.